# Store form parameters between two pages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a form stored in a _form partial that is displayed in two pages. Page A and Page B.

The form works well and posts correctly using GET to the current page.

However when I'm on page A, submit the form, and go to page B, the page doesn't keep the values since params haven't been posted to it.

Should I use a session to keep my search form parameters from page A and set them on page B when it loads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to go about this is either in the session (if it's very small), or in hidden fields (if it's a lot of content for something like a multiline form).

Comment: Or in a cookie.  Also, only do the hidden field if these fields are not a security risk.

Comment: @cpuguy83 it seems he was talking about search, so I assumed there wasn't a security issue involved in exposing the users search. You are correct of course- if it's not something the user should ever see, don't use hidden fields!

Comment: So everytime a user searches, I need to store all the parameters in a session and in my _form I need to check if params[] are full, otherwise  replace the values of the fields to the values in the session. Is that the jist of it?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the params from Page A to Page B from your controller

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController

  def action1
   <do smething>
   redirect_to action2(:param1 => params[:param1], :param2 => params[:param2])
  end

  def action2

  end

end
```

You can use the params hash in the view for Page2 to populate the fields.